# How many numbers of 5 integer digits, ranging from 1 to 9, there are if two of those digits repeat each one exactly two times?

Tags: combinatorics

So we have a number with five digits: XXYYZ. Two of these five digits are equal (X). Then other two digits are equal too (Y). And the last one is other digit (Z). The digits range from $1$ to $9$ and X, Y and Z must be different from each other. Examples: $88922$, $22113$, $77118$

What I know: In first place, we have XXYYZ that can change places between each other, so we have $\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$. Then for X we have $9$ options, for Y we have $8$ options and for Z, $7$ options. So, multiplying everything the result should be $\frac{5!}{2!*2!} * 9 * 8*7$, which we could write as $\frac{5!}{2!*2!} * 7 * \frac{9!}{7!}$. The problem is my book says the answer is $\frac{5!}{2!*2!} * 7 * \frac{9!}{7! *2!}$, and now I just don't know what I did wrong. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that choosing the digits $4$ for $X$, $5$ for $Y$, and $6$ for $Z$, then placing the $X$s in the first two positions, the $Y$s in the last two positions, and the $Z$ in the middle position produces exactly the same number as choosing the digits $5$ for $X$, $4$ for $Y$, and $6$ for $Z$, then placing the $X$s in the last two positions, the $Y$s in the first two positions, and the $Z$ in the middle position, namely $44655$.  Therefore, you have counted each number twice.

Choose which two of the nine digits will each appear twice in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways, choose which of the seven remaining digits will appear once in $\binom{7}{1}$ ways, choose two of the five positions in the number for the smaller of the digits that will appear twice in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, two of the remaining three positions for the larger of the two numbers that will appear twice in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, and fill the remaining position with the number that will appear once.  There are
$$\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$
such numbers, which agrees with the answer in your book.